# Asana Connect (OAuth) can not get token

Tags: asana

when using the asana Oauth to get the Token

the https://app.asana.com/-/oauth_token return

```
Error

No route found
```

Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about what you're sending? Ideally a full HTTP trace (such as you'd get from `curl -v`) would help identify what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create you application in asana

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AuYF.png]

---

GET URL = 'https:// app.asana.com/-/oauth_authorize?client_id='+ setting.client_id
      + '&redirect_uri='  + setting.redirect_uri
      + '&response_type=' + setting.response_type

---

You get the code, POST code URL'https:// app.asana.com/-/oauth_token?grant_type=authorization_code'
            + '&client_id='     + setting.client_id
            + '&client_secret=' + setting.client_secret 
            + '&code='          + query.code 
            + '&redirect_uri='  + setting.redirect_uri

---

The access code is issued for an one hour. POST URL 'https:// app.asana.com/-/oauth_token?grant_type=refresh_token'
            + '&client_id='     + setting.client_id
            + '&client_secret=' + setting.client_secret 
            + '&refresh_token=' + setting.refresh_token  ----- for refresh access co